# UPDATE: Py 3.5.2 + Matplotlib :errors messages

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Sorry for the  second post , but I wanted to include the errors I'm getting.

"import matplotlib" works. 
get_backend() retuns "TkAgg"( change made in RC file)

but "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt returns:
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 114, in 
> > >           _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
> > >           globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in 
> > >           import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 9, in 
> > >           from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name '_tkagg'

Comment: @bobsterman any sequence should work as input to `plot`

Comment: what does `plt.get_backend()` return?  My guess is it has defaulted to `Agg` which is a non-interactive backend.  Dose `plt.save_fig('test.png')` do the right thing?

Comment: @tcaswell  yes to both of your questions, "Agg" and image file was created. Id this something that can be changed in a  confiig file?  Or is it a build issue? TX David

Comment: either modify your `matplotlibrc` file or `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('tkagg'); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.  It is important to call `use` _before_ you import pyplot

Comment: See, http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend Which interactive backends are available will depended on what else is installed on your system

Comment: @tcaswell, Do I just comment out "TkAgg" in the RC file? TX David

Comment: @tcaswell , thanks for your help.that tweek to the rc file did the trick.

Comment: You should answer your own question